# How to control Tamper Monkey dashboard Installed script, so that user cannot disable a script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I have an Internal web portal (opened only from Chrome) in which I am temporarily hiding few options using Tamper Monkey. So this script would be setup in few internal system only. Is there a way I disable the option in Tamper Monkey where users cannot go disable these script in the Tamper Monkey dashboard? This is being done from an organization level.

Is there a way I put this script directly in to my Web Server?

Comment: Not without actually changing the source code of the installed Tampermonkey extension, I would think. Random idea, there might be a way to use a *built-in* userscript (not run through a userscript manager) while preventing access to the Chrome extensions page

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot do that.  **No userscript can alter any extension nor browser settings.**

Nor can even an extension interfere directly with other extensions.

The browser developers are very diligent about blocking all vectors for such attacks that they discover (within reason).

- Your best bet is to **alter the web portal app to deal with the issue.**  It should never, ever, trust what is coming from a "browser" anyway (Always verify your app inputs).
- If you have inflicted *Google Chrome Enterprise* on your users, you can [force-install extensions that they can't disable](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6306504?hl=en).  This still wouldn't stop them from being to disable a Tampermonkey script, but you could write a custom extension that does the same thing.
- If you have full control of the target machines, and depending on details you haven't provided, you may be able to place the machines in ["Kiosk Mode"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kiosk%20mode%20browser&t=ffhp&ia=web).  Although I'm not sure if this would prevent them from clicking Tampermonkey off...
- The second best bet is employee training, coaching, and (last-resort) consequences -- if this is a workplace.
- Another possibility, if you have money and time to burn, is to fork the Chromium source code and make your own browser.

---

It is also *possible*, but almost certainly not cost effective, to place an executable on the user's machines that restricts certain actions.  But you'd be a fool, and/or a government, and/or a crook, to attempt such an approach.

Comment: While the spirit of the answer is correct, enterprise deployments of Chrome allow forced extension install as specified in configuration. Still, it's not possible to solve by force-installing Tampermonkey; see OP's own response on how to deal with it.

Comment: @Xan, good to know; updated the answer.  It's still the exact wrong approach unless you're running a penitentiary or similar.  And, it still won't prevent the real problem, which is improper data vetting at the app.

Comment: It's certainly a fragile approach. You are perfectly correct that changing the app in question is the only good option.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how we solved the issue.

We created a new Chrome Extension and it uses an User script. So rather than depending on Tamper Monkey, we built our own. 
Also when its published in an organization by an Administrator, we can then control the Chrome Extension if it can be disabled or not. Also we can force install of the Extension, when someone disables it.

Comment: That is the way to do it, indeed. Have you tested Incognito as well?

Comment: @Xan Good Point! We cannot auto enable the Extension from Manifest file. But will have to be done manually. This should not be an issue in our case as the internal users will not open the browser in the Incognito mode. Also this is a temporary solution only.